# retrieve values greater than particular value from firebase realtime databasein android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have a local database in Android with some data that contains timestamp. And I have a firebase database that contains same data. Now if I update data in firebase database, suppose I update name and timestamp updated automatically. App also maintains last sync time in preference.

How do I retrieve all data from firebase where timestamp in firebase is greater than timestamp in preference ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Query query = ref.orderByChild("lastUpdatedTimestamp").startAt("1490187991");
```

I'm not sure why you store the timestamp as a string btw. I recommend converting that to a number, so that you don't get caught when we reach the 11th digit (which admittedly will take quite some time).

Comment: tnx for reply. let me try

Comment: it returns all data sir. is this query returns all data which contains timestamp greater than 1490187991?